# How to get product image with product url and attribute option id in order view page magento

Tags: magento-1.9

> My Account => Order => View Order page
>
> Example of Product url + att.

http://example.com/dress-prova-attributes.html?attr=59 
and open product detail page then select the color attribute option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     1. app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

    <?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
    <?php //added for sending image with order

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
            ->load($_item->getProductId());

        $color_id ='';

        if($_options = $this->getItemOptions()){
            foreach ($_options as $_option){
                if($_option['label']=='Color'){
                    $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
                    $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($_option['value']);        
                }
            }
        }
    ?> 
    <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 0px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php 
            if($_item->getProductType() == 'configurable'){
                $product = $_item->getProduct();
                $childrenItems = $_item->getChildrenItems();
                $childItem = reset($childrenItems);
                $product_image = $childItem->getProduct();
            }
            else{
                $product = $_item->getProduct();
                $product_image = $_item->getProduct();
            }
         ?>
            <a href="<?php if(!empty($color_id)){ echo  $product->getProductUrl().'?attr='.$color_id; }else{ echo  $product->getProductUrl(); } ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product_image, 'image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="" style="float: left;" />
            </a>
            <strong>
                <a href="<?php if(!empty($color_id)){ echo $product->getProductUrl().'?attr='.$color_id; }else{  echo $product->getProductUrl(); } ?>" style="text-transform: uppercase; color:#10b2c3; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                </a>
            </strong>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the codes given below:

// First load the product

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Then show the thumbnail where you want using the code given below

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()); ?>" border="0" width="75" />
```

Comment: The question is for **Magento 1.9**

Comment: Sorry,  answer updated

Comment: Yes this question for Magento 1.9 @Dinesh Yadav

Comment: @Rita Jose  you are right but simple product image get this code so.Thank for the reply